# Calling a function from another only when it has finished

Tags: jquery, function, sequence

looking to call a 2nd function once the sequence of delayed fades in the 1st is complete.

I have 2 functions "firstTime" and "loopTime" as below, but only want "loopTime" to run once "firstTime" is complete.

Andy advice on getting this working? e.g. "loopTime" should be called once the last delayed fade in "firstTime" is complete - then "loopTime" should play it's sequence and loop forever...

Possible?

```
function firstTime(callback) {

alert("firstTime")
$(".card h1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3500);
$(".card h1").delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);
$(".card h2").delay(17000).fadeIn(3500);
$(".card h2").delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);

return true;
}

function loopTime () {

alert("loopTime")
$(".card h1").fadeIn(3500);
$(".card h1").delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);
$(".card h2").delay(12000).fadeIn(3500);
$(".card h2").delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);    

}

firstTime(function () {
    loopTime();
});
```

Comment: A quick solution would be to add the callback once the longer fade it's complete. jQuery fadein and out accepts callbacks http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: But the best solution I think is to use the callbacks jQuery function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/

Comment: Please note: all your examples re-use the same selectors repeatedly. You can simply chain them and avoid the overhead. e.g. `$(".card h1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3500).delay(5000).fadeOut(3500)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can chain your animations if they are for the same element. No need for separate lines.

Use your callbacks as second parameters to the last running (longest running) animation:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cL50uh1x/2/

```
function firstTime(callback) {
    $(".card h1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3500).delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);
    $(".card h2").delay(17000).fadeIn(3500).delay(5000).fadeOut(3500, callback);
}

function loopTime() {
    $(".card h1").fadeIn(3500).delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);
    $(".card h2").delay(12000).fadeIn(3500).delay(5000).fadeOut(3500, loopTime);
}

firstTime(loopTime);
```

For `loopTime`, it simply calls itself when the last animation ends. As there are no parameters to your functions, just reference them without calling them (no anonymous function wrappers needed). That even goes for the first call to `firstTime` :)

Comment: @dubbs: I got the feeling you wanted something simpler. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the one that will take more time is this

```
$(".card h2").delay(17000).fadeIn(3500);
```

So you can do this

```
$(".card h2").delay(17000).fadeIn(3500,callback);
```

from the jQuery fadeIn documentation you can pass as second parameter a function to call when it is complete

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

and to make it loop the second you can use setTimer

```
firstTime(function () {
//Every 2 seconds
   setInterval(function () {loopTime();}, 20000);
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Thanks, yep that works, that now called LoopTime once firstTime has ended - how do I make loopTime loop?

Comment: Your anonymous function in `setInterval` is not needed as there are no parameters to `loopTime()`. `setInterval(loopTime, 20000);` will do the same thing
`

Comment: Thanks, but is using a setInterval a good idea? I tried it before and it seemed to be inconsistent...? e.g. is it not better to use a callback so time becomes irrelevant?

Comment: Also the loop suggestion will not work as it will delay the loop from occuring until the timer is complete even on first run after firstTime is completed...

Answer (score 0):

In `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` you need to add a callback as the second parameter. [Official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). For the looping part you might want to look into `setInterval()`, [here is the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

```
function firstTime(callback) {

alert("firstTime")
$(".card h1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3500);
$(".card h1").delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);

// this call could be use to trigger the second function since it is the last completed call
$(".card h2").delay(17000).fadeIn(3500, function(){ setinterval(function() { loopTime () }, 100) } ); 

$(".card h2").delay(5000).fadeOut(3500);

return true;
}
```

Another solution, you might want to consider is using a functional reactive plugin. There is [bacon.js](http://baconjs.github.io/)

Comment: OK, and how to make the loopTime play over and over again performing the fad sequences in a row?

Comment: I wouldn't use set interval for event listen. It will do the job but you will use CPU resources needlessly and you will have to fix the issue with timers in iOS6. jQuery provides callbacks solutions, I recommend to use it.